# How can I convert mysql_fetch_assoc to PDO?

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
$result = $db->("SELECT `count` FROM playerCount");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo $row['count'];
}
```

How can I convert line:
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

to PDO?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->query(...);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```